# Is it a good practice to iterate a hashmap?

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, hash, collections

This is a very generic question, I am just taking an example of Java HashMap.

I am having a Hashmap.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> idPriceMap=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
idPriceMap.put(10,20);
idPriceMap.put(11,25);
idPriceMap.put(12,0);
idPriceMap.put(13,100);
idPriceMap.put(14,20);
idPriceMap.put(15,40);
idPriceMap.put(16,90);
```

Requirements might differ, for e.g.:

UseCase1: I want a value for a particular key assuming that I know the key (PS. I know in this scenario HashMap is the best structure )

Usecase2: I want to get all the values.

For now consider the UseCase2 only. The question is: Is that good practice?

In another scenario I am having UseCase1 & UseCase2 both of them at the same time. What would you suggest?

I tried to Google it, all i got is best ways to iterate a HashMap. :(

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking?  Yes hashmap can be used for both cases finding value by key or iterating over all values.

Comment: @brso05 Is it a good practice to iterate an hashmap ?? We can iterate a list too,According to the use cases which one would be the best ??
Hope i am clear now.

Comment: If you need both cases then HashMap if you just need to iterate then either one is fine.  HashMap only allows key = value keys can not be repeated.  If you don't need to access a specific value associated with a key but just need access to the values themselves then a list works fine.

Comment: Iterating through a `Map` is perfectly normal.  Why would it be a bad practice?

Comment: What do you mean with "value", is it as defined by the Map interface?

Answer (score 0):

UseCase1 (value for a specific key): hashap is the best structure for this, yes

UseCase2 (all values): because you want all values, it does not matter if its a hashmap, a list or a tree

so im not sure what your question is. but you could easily get the time complexity for different data-structures if you google for it:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table (see the right side big O notation)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mixed usage scenario, then there is no generic answer to your question. It depends on the frequency and distribution (scenario 1 or 2) of your requests, and the volatility of your map contents.

Recommendation: Just use the standard hash map. Then profile your application. Most of the time the bottleneck is not where you expect it first and you achieve performance gains with cheap changes in other places.

If the hash map is really the bottle neck:

Ask again, with specific frequencies of your usages ;)

If you want to do "premature optimization" (See the good old c2 wiki: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), then just put your values in a separate array to speed up the request on the complete values a little. But if you have lots of modifications, then your overall performance will degrade. That is the same thing like having a database index or not....

Hope that was useful.